# Rails 3 gem usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I installed this gem in my Gemfile https://github.com/peter-murach/github#readme. I am trying to call 'github = Github.new' in a controller's method but I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationsController::Github
```

if I require 'github_api' I get this

```
cannot load such file -- github_api
```

How and where do I call gem's methods?

Comment: Where are you trying to `require 'github_api'`?